# Why there is no std::copy_until function in C++ standard?

Tags: c++, std

C++ standard library provides really awesome stuff (`std::copy`, `std::count`, `std::remove` etc.), but i have no idea why there's no `std::copy_until`, which would copy data from input iterator to output until test (eg. lambda) returns `true`.

Here's example implementation:

```
template<class inputIt, class outputIt, class comp_t>
outputIt copy_until(inputIt in, outputIt out, comp_t comp) {
    while (comp(*in)) {
        *out = *in;
        ++out;
        ++in;
    }

    return out;
}
```

I thought that just no one wrote a paper or something, but maybe function like that is somehow bad / suggests that my code is misdesigned?

Comment: @PeteBecker Right, it makes sense – fixed.

Comment: If you can write it yourself in less than 10 lines, why should `std` provide it?

Comment: You may want to avoid reading the input iterator twice, otherwise looks perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @abelenky: Half the functions of `<algorithm>` can be written in less than 10 lines.

Comment: @abelenky: well, the other functions provided aren't exactly the longest pieces of code in existence ... it's about utility, how useful is it?

Comment: I would imagine, it's more "efficient" to find the end iterator first, then copy the range in one go? (NOTE: I put efficient in double quotes as it should be taken with a grain of salt..), for example: `copy(begin(x), find_if(begin(x), end(x), some_func), dest)` probably achieves the same?

Comment: 1.) Allocating the correct amount of data in the output vector can't be done beforehand. 2.) You don't provide boundaries (like `in.end()`). 3.) You can easily write this yourself with `std::copy_if` https://godbolt.org/g/jtxWzo

Comment: @SimonKraemer, `copy_if` has different semantics..

Comment: @Nim in a template you can dispatch to different implementations based off whether types fulfill certain requirements, though, so an implementation could do that on ContiguousIterators.

Comment: @Nim I have added an example that does exactly what OP described using `std::copy_if`

Comment: @SimonKraemer Please, don't refer to my implementation (even different args can be taken), it's just a concept. And `std::copy_if` isn't designed to copy like that as it has to iterate over all the elements of container, `copy_until` would stop earlier and use way less CPU.

Comment: @SimonKraemer, I think the OP's intention is that the copy operation should cease on first mismatch of the condition... `copy_if` will go all the way through to the end and copy every matching element - hence difference semantics?

Comment: @Nim `copy(begin(x), find_if(begin(x), end(x), some_func), dest)` does same thing, but has to iterate over data 2x more.

Comment: The answer to *"Why there is no std::copy_until function in C++ standard?"* is probably: (A) Nobody ever bothered to write a proposal for it, (B) it was proposed but the ISO committee did not find it useful enough or (C) it was considered useful but unlike other new C++11 algorithms, there was a lack of experience with existing implementations or extensions, so the conservative choice was to not add it. See also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2666.pdf

Comment: @KamilKoczurek, for sure - there could be some optimisation opportunities - where with the compound operation, the copy would effectively boil down to a `memcopy`, where as with the naive implementation above, it most likely will end up copy constructing... anyway - I put "efficient" in double quotes for that reason..

Comment: @Nim Yes, you are right I did not really think about that `copy_if` always checks the whole array.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek Looks like boost has such a function: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/boost/algorithm/copy_until_idp37513056.html

Comment: @SimonKraemer I don't know why I didn't find it, thanks.

Comment: @ChristianHackl If it would be an answer instead of a comment, I'd mark it as good one. :)

Comment: I'll turn it into one later, too difficult on a phone...

Comment: C++17 allows for sentinel values in range-based-for-loop, perhaps the standard will adopt this in the future for the other functions in the standard library. Then this `copy_until` function could be the same as the `std::copy` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to *"Why there is no `std::copy_until` function in C++ standard?"* is probably one of these:

- Nobody ever bothered to write a proposal for it.
- It was proposed but the ISO committee did not find it useful enough.
- It was considered useful but unlike other new C++11 algorithms, there was a lack of experience with existing implementations or extensions, so the conservative choice was to not add it.

See also the ["More STL algorithms (revision 2)" proposal](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2666.pdf). Even though it does not mention something like `copy_until`, it sheds some light on why certain algorithms (like `copy_if`) were added and others (like `lexicographical_compare_3way`) were not.